# Script to calculate number of lines between two strings across multiple files

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have some files which are thousands of lines in size. My task is to calculate all the lines between two strings - "access-list $f-datacenter" AND "ip access-list" in each of those files. $f is a variable which I will be putting in. The patterns looks like this  -

```
Beginning of file
.
.
.
.
access-list $f-datacenter
.
.
.
ip access-list
.
.
END OF FILE
```

I am working on a script which will calculate the number of lines between these two strings in multiple files. My script inputs a variable in string # and the file name from an array I define -

```
fnames=( x y ); for f in ${fnames[@]}; do awk '/access-list $f-datacenter/ {b=NR; next} /ip access-list/ {print NR-b-1; exit}' $f-datacenter.txt ; done
```

However, I see this script returning wrong line numbers each time it is run.  For example, if the actual line numbers are in the 600 range, the script will only show me something around 200.

When I run the same commands individually like this I get the correct line #s -

```
awk '/access-list x-datacenter/ {b=NR; next} /ip access-list/ {print NR-b-1; exit}' $x-datacenter.txt
awk '/access-list y-datacenter/ {b=NR; next} /ip access-list/ {print NR-b-1; exit}' $y-datacenter.txt
```

So, question is why does this fail in a script and how to fix it?

Comment: Are their multiple instances of this pair in each file, or just one?  Is is GUARANTEED to be paired -- if one line exists the other will, too?

Answer (score 0):

Getting shell variables into [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) may be done in several ways.

This is the best way to do it. It uses the `-v` option: (P.S. use a space after `-v` or it will be less portable. E.g., `awk -v var=` not `awk -vvar`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fnames=( x y ); 
for f in ${fnames[@]}; do 
     awk -v name="$f"  'BEGIN{
            start_pattern = "access-list " name "-datacenter"
            end_pattern = "ip access-list"
          }
          $0 ~ start_pattern{ b=NR } 
          b && $0 ~ end_pattern  { print NR-b-1; exit}
          ' "$f-datacenter.txt" 
done
```

Comment: Quick question. Why are u using: b && $0 ~ endpattern? $0 and endpattern is clear but why the b?

Comment: @JFS31: I want to make sure that variable `b` is set, for example start pattern not found, and end pattern found, then it will print current record number - 1,  so `b && $0 ~ end_pattern`

Comment: I see. Thats very smart. Thank you for the answer :)